# return the object with the property of lowest cost

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

How to make a function which return the object that has the lowest cost.

```js
sandwitch = [
    {
        'type':"Italian",
        'cost':7.69 , 
        'isVageterian':false
    },
    {
        'type':"Veggie",
        'cost':5.50 , 
        'isVageterian':true
    },
    {
        'type':"Jackfruit",
        'cost':8.50 , 
        'isVageterian':true
    },
]
```

Comment: Put the first element of the array in a `result` variable. Loop through the array, checking if its cost is lower than `result.cost`. If it is, replace `result`. Finally, return `result`.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

```js
sandwitch = [{
    'type': "Italian",
    'cost': 7.69,
    'isVageterian': false
  },
  {
    'type': "Veggie",
    'cost': 5.50,
    'isVageterian': true
  },
  {
    'type': "Jackfruit",
    'cost': 8.50,
    'isVageterian': true
  },
]

const lowest = sandwitch.reduce(
  (prev, curr) =>
  prev.cost < curr.cost ?
  prev :
  curr
)

alert(lowest.cost);
```